# Oracle Database Documentation Lock Modes Example

Tags: sql, oracle

[image].

Oracle Database Documentation provides this example of two transactions concurently obtaining explicit locking. I believe there is a mistake, as bottom(right) transaction should be able to obtain SRX lock even if 1st (left) transaction got RS lock.

What is your opinion? Just want to make sure that indeed it is an error.

[Documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADFNS/sql-processing-for-application-developers.htm#ADFNS00203)

Answer (score 1):

Just done a test, your opinion is right.  Result as below:

session 1:

```
SQL> LOCK TABLE CENZHGL.LOCK_TEST IN ROW SHARE MODE;
Table(s) locked
```

session 2:

```
SQL> LOCK TABLE CENZHGL.LOCK_TEST IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
ORA-00054
SQL> LOCK TABLE CENZHGL.LOCK_TEST IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT；
Table(s) locked
```

Oracle lock model mutex relationship as below:

```
    lock mode |       lock name               |  permit  |  exclusion
--------------|-------------------------------|----------|--------------
        2     |       Row Share               |  2,3,4,5 |     6
        3     |Row Exclusive Table Lock       |  2,3     |   4,5,6
        4     |      Share Table Lock         |  2,4     |   2,5,6
        5     |Share Row Exclusive Table Lock |  2       |   3,4,5,6
        6     |    Exclusive Table Lock       |          |   2,3,4,5,6
```